# Adding a ClickHandler to the background of a FlowPanel in GWT

Tags: gwt

I'm new to GWT, and my search queries didn't turn up what I'm looking for, but I'm afraid I'm not phrasing them correctly, so I apologize if this is a simple/duplicate question.

I'm currently trying to figure out how to add a ClickHandler to the area of a FlowPanel that is not occupied by a specific Widget. I know that I can simply add a ClickHandler by wrapping the entire FlowPanel inside a FocusPanel, but that then triggers when any of the widgets inside the flow panel are clicked on. The widgets are typically composite widgets with complicated structures themselves.

My ultimate goal here is to process a click when a user clicks in empty space, but allow the individual widgets to have their own unique click handlers if the user clicks on a specific widget.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to wrap FlowPanel inside a FocusPanel, unless you need that focus. You can simply `myFlowPanel.addDomHandler(myClickHandler, ClickEvent.getType())`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

(A) Add the same click handler to all of your widgets, and then inside `onClick` perform different actions based on which widget was the source of a click.

(B) Get the mouse position (from ClickEvent), and then iterate through child widgets to see if this mouse position falls inside one of them.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I did arrive at a similar but slightly different solution of keeping a list of the widgets, then doing `event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget()` followed by checking each of the widgets by `getElement().isOrHasChild(targetElement)`. This is similar to your option (B) but uses the element hierarchy rather than position directly. Is there a reason one method might be preferred over the other?